# How to store tokens in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm doing a small project to prepare for server linking, but I'm trying to save the token in Userdefault! I don't know how to code.

```
var headers: [String: String]? {
    switch self {
    case .signIn:
        return nil
        
    case .renewalToken:
        guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.set("userID", forKey: "signIn") else{
        return ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token]
        }
    default:
        guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.set(<#T##value: Any?##Any?#>, forKey: <#T##String#>)
        return ["Authorization": "Bearer " + token]
    }
}
```

This code can be obtained by putting it in the code below using the header, but I don't know what to do with the token

```
   func get(_ api: TargetType) -> DataRequest{
    return AF.request(baseURI + api.path, method: .get, parameters: api.parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: api.headers, interceptor: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should not store sensitive information into the user defaults. I would recommend you to use keychain. It's highly secure.

There are several Libraries which give simple and easy to use interfaces of keychain

`SwiftyKeychainWrapper` is one of them:

https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

Update -

You need to access user default values using following code:

`let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “keyName”) ?? “”`

Note: if token doesn't exist then you can just navigate user to the Login screen for authentication and regeneration of token.

Comment: If I use a keychain too, I can see something better.

let token = UserDefaults.standard.string (forKey :“keyName”) ?? “”

Is it possible to save if accessed with this code? If so, what should I put in'forkey'?

Comment: `KeyName`, you can name it anything but it should be same for saving and accessing it.

Comment: Go through this tutorial it will guide you through the usage of user defaults: https://medium.com/better-programming/userdefaults-in-swift-4-d1a278a0ec79

Comment: @ga-yo if it satisfies your requirement, you can upvote it and Mark the answer correct